# How to hide title on 'highlights' - Themify feature

Tags: themes, title

I am using Themify's Flat theme and in the Highlights I want to hide the title of my highlights. Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider that people reading your Question don't have Themify. Please, post all the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the theme, but assuming the title's class is title put this into your css file: `.title { display: none; }`.  If it is an id put this in there `#title { display: none; }`.  And if it is an html element like h1 use this `h1 { display: none; }`.